# Get array details PHP

Tags: php, arrays, get

I have a google map on this page, all markers were generated by submit postcodes. So I have the array below, loop info of each marker,
 imploded as ("array", "array") format, I am trying to click on a infoWindow and display the according marker details on details.php. 
 The problem is everything is on the button onclick event, only a simple get on the second page.

This is working, but it is a very bad way. Because the limit to URL length and security reasons;
 I would like to be able to get an array info from details.php page, 
 and the button onclick event trigger url looks like:  `details.php?marker=id`

I don't know what is the best way to go about this, can someone pointing me to the right direction please?

**index.php**

```
       $info = array();

       foreach($stmt as $x)
        {
          $info[] =            
            "<h4>" . $x['name'] . "</h4><hr />".
            "<h5>Address: </h5>" . $x['Address']."<br />" . 
            "<h5>Postcode: " . $x['postcode'] ."</h5><br />" . 

            "<button onclick='window.location.href= \\\"details.php?marker=". "<h4>" . $x['name'] . "</h4><hr />".
            "<h5>Address: </h5>" . $x['address']."<br />" . "<h5>Postcode: " . $x['postcode'] ."</h5><br />" .  "\\\" ' >
            View Details</button>"; 
        }           
        $i=' "'.implode('","', $info).'"';
```

**details.php**

```
echo $infomarker = $_GET['marker'];
```

Comment: unless you have some way of pulling the data from DB or wherever you are getting it from on details.php by ID, then you're out of luck.  Are you storing this data?  Like where is $stmt coming from?  If its coming from your own database, then just pass the ID, and pull from database on details.php

Comment: it is stored in the database

Comment: K, well then you just answered your own question.  Just pass the ID, and pull it from the database on details.php.  Simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `$x['id']` insted of `$x['name']` which is unique in your database and also use `base64_encode()` for encryption of your id `"details.php?marker=".base64_encode($x['id'])."`

In your details.php

`$infomarker = base64_decode($_GET['marker']);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes base64 encode can hide the id number, however this way I only got one single result for all my markers. So I will try ajax suggestion now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using AJAX to get the info from details.php and then load it into your InfoWindow.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realise how simple this was, all I need is use that id, write it inside a sql statement in details page then call any part of the statement out. Thanks everyone. Thanks to @Manjeet Barnala for encode tips.

Comment: Thank You very much buddy...  @user999